# how to fetch the number type data from html to jsp

Tags: html, jsp, servlets

I am unable to fetch the following data....it always shows null

I have following html page

```
<html>
<body>
<input type="number" name="quantity" min="1">
<form action="buy.jsp" method=post>
<input type= "submit" value=submit>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And the jsp page

```
<html>
<body>
<% out.print(request.getParameter("quantity")); %>  // it is always returning null
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How are you sending the data in first place, without a form?

Comment: You must be having an html form or something to send the value!!!?

Comment: I have the form but i did't mention it...

Comment: i have now mentioned it here

Comment: Your input field is out of the form element

Comment: Also not all browsers support the input of type `number`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your html to one below,

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="buy.jsp" method=post>
  <input type="number" name="quantity" min="1">
  <input type= "submit" value=submit>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the code in the first page as follow:

```
  <html>
<body>
<form action="buy.jsp">
  <input type="number" name="quantity" min="1">
  <input type= "submit" value=submit>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

As of the second page, you need to use Param in order to get the data from the first page as follow:

```
 <html>
<head><title> Any Title<\title><\head>
<body>

The Quantity is: ${param.quantity}

</body>
</html>
```